# How to set spring-boot properties based on other runtime properties

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot, environment, applicationcontext

I want to set spring-boot properties based on other properties passed during runtime.

For example: java -Dmyprop=foo -jar app.jar

The property "spring.config.name" should be "foo-dev.yml".

The property "spring.config.name" should be constructed based on runtime property "myprop".

How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you could use Spring profile, to make spring to use the application-{profileName}.properties file